# Download pdf or image through ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I would like to send a lot of data through ajax request to my server which will generate `pdf` or `jpg` format according to that data.

Now i have done all that, my issue is to how output that generated `pdf/jpg` back to the user trough ajax? I guess i might be able to use `json` for that, but im not really sure how, and i think there would be a lot issues with `pdf`.

Also if some one gonna suggest using `form` with `hidden` inputs that will not work since i have really big `multidimensional array` with lot's of data and it would simply take to much effort to make it work.

By the way, i am using `jquery`, but anything else is acceptable as long as it does the job done without making me to rewrite half of my script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript/jquery to download file via POST with JSON data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499597/javascript-jquery-to-download-file-via-post-with-json-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To display a JPG**

1. AJAX: You can return the *data* hex encoded (be sure to set the content type appropriately: `header('Content-type: image/jpeg')`).  Then you just inject an `<img/>` element into the DOM and set it's `src` attribute to the returned [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).
2. HTML: Also, you could inject the `<img/>`'s with a normal `src` URL to some location on your server.

**For PDF**

It's a little more tricky.  Some browsers display PDF's natively (Chrome/Firefox), others rely on optional third-party plugins.  You can detect these plugins, but can't control whether the PDF is displayed in a window/`frame` or is downloaded.

If you choose to display, you can create [a new window/tab](http://webdesign.about.com/od/javascript/a/aa030600c.htm) to display it or [display it in an iframe dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908554/open-dynamically-generated-pdf-in-tab-or-iframe).